# FullCalendar header buttons missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) as below
and have defined header section, everything works ok except header where it's only showing title but
next, prev, month view etc buttons are missing

if I remove word 'title' it removes title so it seems to be doing something but just not showing buttons, any ideas why? am I missing something?
my code looks like below:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventSources:
    [{
        url: url,
        color: '#ffdce5',
        textColor: 'black' 
    }]

})
```

Comment: have you added css file for fullcalendar?

Comment: yes, along with jquery I have added in this order, fullcalendar.min.css, fullcalendar.print.css, moment.js, fullcalendar.min.js

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement, that will be easy for us to help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kxchmytn/
it doesn't show any buttons, am I missing something? was hoping to see buttons like this demo: http://fullcalendar.io/

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Having just had the same problem I suspect your issue is that you're missing the `media="print"` attribute on the `fullcalendar.print.css` style sheet link.

Comment: media="print" it is
<link href="~/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />

Answer (score 0):

And if you're using Zend Framework to append the stylesheet, you can use this to add the media="print"...

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/jquery-plugins/fullcalendar.print.css', 'print');
```