# Fullcalendar Unknown option 'header' version 5.5.1

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-5

I try to use fullcalendar and show header nav buttons but not working

JS code

```
$(function(){
      var calendarEl = $('#calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar($(calendarEl)[0], {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        weekends: true,
        navLinks: true,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'year,month,basicWeek,basicDay'

        },
      });
      calendar.render();
    });
```

Thank you for you help, it's for work...

[fullcalendar header toolbar buttons not showing when application css and javascript tags are initialized on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198933/fullcalendar-header-toolbar-buttons-not-showing-when-application-css-and-javascr)
Not working

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/header
not working

[FullCalendar header buttons missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681573/fullcalendar-header-buttons-missing)
not working

Answer (score 4):

You are using fullcalendar v5, and following old documentation, here is [V5 DOCS](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options)

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  headerToolbar: { center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek' }, // buttons for switching between views
});
```